Getting appointment in another state due to available dates
I've received my Letter of Acceptance from my university in Germany, and I need to arrive between July 1st and 10th, 2024. However, I'm unable to find a VFS Global visa appointment in Delhi. I'm from Haryana. Can I book an appointment in Hyderabad, considering I'm not getting one in Delhi but there are available slots in Hyderabad?

You are presumably trying to apply for a type D / national visa, not a Schengen short-stay visa, correct? This is important because it means the German rules apply and they can be different from Schengen rules.

You could contact German embassy , they could help in my opinion you could try asking VFS Hyderabad also but they might be in a position to help you better , unfortunately embassy’s are clogged with people who wants to go to Germany you should have prepared well in advance unless you can prove your place of residence in Hyderabad

Have you subscribed on the waitlist?


I'm from Haryana. Can I book an appointment in Hyderabad, considering I'm not getting one in Delhi but there are available slots in Hyderabad?

No, for a Student visa you must apply through VFS in New Delhi which is is responsible for your area (Haryana).


National Visa
Step 2 – Schedule an appointment
Appointments are booked at the foreign mission responsible for your place of residence or habitual abode. The German missions abroad in India are geographically divided into official districts. Responsibility is based exclusively on the applicant's current main place of residence. Place of birth or nationality are not relevant.


Sources:

National Visa - Federal Foreign Office

German Embassy New Delhi



